# Embedding Quick Time movies in HTML Pages

Tags: html, quicktime

I am trying to embed QuickTime movies into my HTML/ASPX pages but somehow they work on local machine but when i deploy them on my server they dont play at all. I tried all sorts of options but still unable to find a reason for that. 
anybody else have been though this issue ?

I did a quick research and find few resources but even though following them works on my local machine but not on production. I am wandering , do i need to setup some sort of streaming to just embed few videos files or what ?

and yeah i did follow the apple article too (who put the blame on simply internet explorer) while my firefox shows the same result. I got the image (startup) but no video as i click to play.

One video is of 11 MB while other is 50 MB. I renamed the files by removing all the spaces now and i can see the QuickTime plugin initiating but after a while the Question Mark is appearing on the QuickTime Logo. Mime type is also video/quicktime so which is correct.

Comment: If you get a 404 error when you try to go to the videos directly, they aren't uploaded properly. Can you show the line(s) of HTML you're using to try and embed them?

Answer (score 1):

Actually the issue was not with my Page, The QuickTime movies require QuickTime (mov movies) and ITune (m4v movies)to be installed on Server. Hence after installing both softwares, the issues are resolved

Answer (score 0):

How large are the videos? If you are not streaming the plugin may need to download the entire file before it can play, whereas locally it does not. That could cause a very long pause before the movie starts.

Answer (score 0):

Point your browser directly to the movie's URL — not the containing page. See what error you get. Also, is the MIME type correct?